# Project structure issue

Tags: c++

My goal is to achieve a test project on VisualStudio 2019.

I think that my main problem is with How to structure my project. Because, at the end, I find many files and don't know how to manage them.

These are the test .cpp files :

**TIStream.cpp** :

```
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>
#include <boost/test/data/test_case.hpp>
#include <boost/test/data/monomorphic.hpp>
#include "../ReemasCore/serialization.h"
#include <string.h>

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE(Serialization_InMemStream)

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(InMemStreamCtor_SizePositif_CorrectPointer)
{
    auto in = std::make_unique<InMemStream>(10);

    BOOST_TEST(in->ppStart != nullptr);
    BOOST_TEST(in->ppCurrent == in->ppStart);
    BOOST_TEST(in->ppEnd == in->ppStart + 10);
}
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END()
```

**TTCPServer :**

```
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE(TCP_SERVER)

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(Server_Case1)
{
    BOOST_TEST(1 == 1);
    BOOST_TEST(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END()
```

Comment: Please, do not post *images* of the warning/error logs. Instead, please post the **actual text** of the error in your question post.

Comment: Are your tests using code from `ReemasProject`? It doesn't look like you *link* that code to your tests. It would seem you could reorganize the project to make `ReemasProject` into a library, and link that library to the tests.

Comment: @squareskittles in fact I did not change anything from `ReemasProject` . It's generated automaticaly when I created the project and it holds a simple `cout Hello main` program in the ReemasProject.cpp file and `#include<iostream>` in ReemasProject.h file . I will note use it! But I don't know if that will cause problems if I delete all the folder!

Comment: @squareskittles please I did not understand what you advice me to do when you said : `reorganize the project to make ReemasProject into a library, and link that library to the tests.`

Comment: `error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol main referenced in function "int __cdecl invoke_main(void)" ` so is the function `invoke_main()` somewhere in your project?

Comment: Based on on [this mailing](https://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2007/12/131748.php) the dynamic version of Boost Test doesn't contain the main function. So if you want to use the shared version of Boost Test you need to follow the instructions from [Boost Test doc](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/usage_variants.html#boost_test.usage_variants.shared_lib). As you didn't shared the source code, I just guessing that you might forgot the `#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE test module name` line before the include.

Comment: @KamilCuk I don't have `invoke_main()` function in my project

Comment: @JánosBenjaminAntal You can take a look at the source code, I have edited the question. I am not putting `#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE test module name` in my source code.

Comment: So put it. `BOOST_TEST_MODULE macro needs to be defined before the include and should be set to test module name.`

Comment: @KamilCuk is right, you need to put that before the include. As the documentation says it must be defined exactly for one compilation unit of your test module. As you create different executables for every test, then it practically means you have to put it into every test source file before the `#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>` line.

Comment: @Gonn Did it help?

Comment: @JánosBenjaminAntal Thank you! That works now! I have added `BOOST_TEST_MODULE macro` in every test source and now I am able to run my tests ! You can set it as response so I can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [this mailing](https://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2007/12/131748.php) the dynamic version of Boost Test doesn't contain the main function from version 1.34.1 and up. So if you want to use the shared version of Boost Test you need to follow the instructions from [Boost Test doc](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/usage_variants.html#boost_test.usage_variants.shared_lib).

You have to put `#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE test module name` before the `#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>`. As the documentation says it must be defined exactly for one compilation unit of your test module. As you create different executables for every test, then it practically means you have to put it into every test source file.